# angular $resource not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a very simple address application in AngularJS. It connects to an API using `$resource`.

The ID I use is the mobilephone number of the person (I know it's not the best way to do it, but it's just an sample application to show a 3-tier application setup) So I've 2 pages with the same form:

[image: insert and edit form]

The problem i'm facing is that it uses the same $resource for saving a new address and saving an edited address. When iḿ saving a new address it has to use the url `http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/contacts/` without an id appended on it (the new ID it will get on the api/database side is the filled in mobile phone number) 
When I edit an existing address and click the save button it has to use another url; `http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/contacts/@mobilePhone`.

So i've read the angular documentation on https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource which states that you can override your paramDefaults in your actions. So that is what I try to do using this code:

```
$resource('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/contacts/:id',{id:'@mobilePhone'},{
        get: {
            method: 'GET'
        }, update: {
            method: 'PUT'
        }, save: {
            method: 'POST',
            id:''
        }
    },{});
```

which seems to be correct given the information. It appends the mobilePhone number on every GET and every PUT the get and update method respectively. When it calls the save method it should override the `:id` with an empty string, but it doesn't do that. 
Clearly i'm doing something wrong.

If you need more code snipets let me know, I tried to keep it as clean as possible.

## Update:

This is how I call the save method:

```
.... 
.controller('MovieCreateController',function($scope,$state,$stateParams,Movie){

    $scope.movie=new Movie();

    $scope.addMovie=function(){

        $scope.movie.$save(function(){
            $state.go('movies');
        });
    }

}
```

And this is the edit method:

```
....
 .controller('MovieEditController',function($scope,$state,$stateParams,Movie){

    $scope.updateMovie=function(){
        $scope.movie.$update(function(){
            $state.go('movies');
        });
    };

    $scope.loadMovie=function(){
        $scope.movie=Movie.get({id:$stateParams.id});
    };

    $scope.loadMovie();
});
```

Comment: HI , please refer https://www.sitepoint.com/creating-crud-app-minutes-angulars-resource/

Comment: Yes I did build it on that basis (coincidently) but I can't figure it out with the information given there.

Comment: Please can you add your post and put requests how are you calling them?

Comment: @Parshuram, I've updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not much code in your question, so I'll try to explain what you should do to use $resource.

Have a look at following code:

```
// The $resource service is a helper to create a 'constructor' function 
// Contact below is a function 
var Contact = $resource('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/contact/:id',{id:'@mobilePhone'}, {
get: {
    method: 'GET' // You don't need to override the GET
}, update: {
    method: 'PUT'
}, save: {
    method: 'POST'
}});

// Be sure to create an 'entity' from the Contact $resource
// The 'new' will create a $resource instance with $update, $save methods overridden methods
var contact = new Contact({name: 'foobar'});
contact.$save(); // Will send a POST request

contact.mobilePhone = 2; // This is your id !
contact.$update();  // Will send a PUT request
```

If your resources always have a RESTful representation, I suggest that you use, as per suggested at [angular discussion on issue#9807](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9807):

```
resource.prototype.$save = function() {
    if (this.id) {
        return this.$update();
    } else {
        return this.$create();
    }
};
```

..rather that always overriding your $resource methods.

Answer (score -1):

This is how you need to call your save method
    $scope.movie=new Movie();

```
$scope.addMovie=function(){
    $scope.movie.$save(function(){
        $state.go('movies');
    });
}
```

This is how you need to call your edit method

```
 $scope.movie=new Movie();
$scope.updateMovie=function(){
    $scope.movie.$update({ "mobilePhone": $stateParams.id},function(){
        $state.go('movies');
    });
};
```

For that you need to create a factory for $resource.which is always recommendable

Try this

```
.factory('movie', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/contacts/:id',{id:'@mobilePhone'},{}, {
        update: { method: 'PUT' },
        query: {
            method: 'GET',
            isArray: false
        }
    })
}])
```

Inject your factory in your controller

```
.controller('MovieCreateController',['$scope','$state','$stateParams','movie',function($scope,$state,$stateParams,Movie){
}]);
```

Comment: This did not solve it for me. It wasn't even working unless I removed the `$scope.movie=new Movie();` from the edit method. Then it worked the same as it was before.

Comment: nop you need to instantiate the resource, not another object, see @FrancoisMurel answer/